# Database Design: One set of tables for each entity type or a generic set for all entity types

Tags: database, entity

My company organizes a gourmet festival yearly. The festival has many events running during its duration. I am tasked with designing the festival website with a CMS (Content Management System).

There are 3 main types of entities - Event, Establishment, Person. An event has many participating establishments (sponsors, restaurants, hotels) and persons (chefs, winery representatives, mixologists).

Each entity can have many categories, many documents, photo galleries and linking to entities of other types. Which is better - Case 1 or Case 2 (see below)?

**[CASE 1]** - a set of tables for each entity type:

Tables for Event: event, eventCategory, eventDocument, eventGallery, event_establishment, event_person

Tables for Establishment: establishment, establishmentCategory, establishmentGallery, establishment_person

Tables for Person: person, personCategory, personDocument, personGallery

Sample columns for personDocument table: docId, docFilename

Note that the above columns will be exactly the same for eventDocument and establishmentDocument.

**[CASE 2]** - a table for each entity type, a type table and a generic set of tables:

Tables: event, establishment, person, entityType, entityCategory, entityDocument, entityGallery, entity_entity

Sample columns for entityDocument: docId, entityTypeId, docFilename

Appreciate any advice - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just my opinion, but I've been doing this a while.

**Case 1** is by far the most easy to maintain and the most recommended in my experience. You can manage your entities and depending on what language you're using to write your site, you could talk advantage of some ORM frameworks that will make your life even easier again.

**Case 2**, doing this in an SQL database will cause you many issues.  You'll end up writing lots of un-nessary code to try and detect types, make sure you're doing the correct joins. It will be a nightmare!  I really can't think of any advantage of doing it this way.

You could have a **case 3** of a No-SQL datastore.  Like MongoDB or RavenDB.  There is no structure to worry about.  What you put in is what you get out and no translation whatsoever. (with RavenDB at least).  No-SQLData Stores are a lot faster for large scale applications, but they do take a while to get your head around using them correctly.

I suggest you go for **Case 1**

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I used Case 1 last year but have been thinking whether things can be improved - the columns for the supplementary tables (category, document, gallery) are the same and with each new entity type, another set of 6 tables or more needs to be added.

The gallery shown above is oversimplified as it needs another table to hold info on the multiple photos in each gallery. Worried about cluttering up the CMS user interface also.